# Selectively returning JSON object results

Tags: javascript, json, jquery

I am trying to selectively return results from a standard JSON file using the following code:

```
var filters = { manufacturer: "Samsung" };

// filters initialised, now getJSON with filters
$.getJSON("phones.json", filters, function(result)
{
    alert(result.phones.length);
}); // end getJSON
```

What I want to do is return only objects where the "manufacturer" is Samsung. JSON looks like this:

```
{
    "phones": [{
        "basic": {
            "id" : "1",
            "name": "Samsung Galaxy S III",
            "manufacturer": "Samsung",
```

etc etc...

It's not working, it's not filtering the JSON at all. Can anyone help?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't see a way other than doing it on the server side. i.e. if you want to transfer only the filtered data. If you are OK with transferring the whole thing and then filtering on the client side, you can do it entirely in JS.

Answer (score 1):

`$.getJSON()` doesn't support filtering, so assuming your `phones.json` is a static file with no server side processing, you'll have to filter on the client side:

```
$.getJSON("phones.json", function(result)
{
    var filtered = [];
    $.each(result.phones, function(key, value){
        if(value.basic.manufacturer == 'Samsung'){
            filtered.push(value);
        }
    });

    console.log(filtered);
});
```

The above stores the filtered phones in `filtered`.

Comment: // filters initialised, now getJSON with filters
    $.getJSON("phones.json", function(result) 
    {
        var matchedPhones = new Array();

        $.each(result, function(k,v) 
     {
      for (var i=0; i < result.phones.length; i++) 
      {
       // manual test
       if (v[i].basic.manufacturer === "Samsung")
       { 
        // store this phone in our new object
        matchedPhones.push(v[i]); 
       }
      };
   
        });

   etc...